# HTML Textbox writing

Tags: html

Hey So I have a project for school where I have to create a website and in the website there has to be a quiz. The questions are asking for numbers as answers, so I cannot use radio buttons. I know how to make textboxes and submit buttons but I dont think the box is getting the information, so I was wondering if someone could help me fix my code

Here is the end of what I have

*This is not the question I am asking this is just so I can get the code working

```
<P><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Submit"> </FORM>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>

</FORM>function getAnswer(input) { if (input == "3.14") {alert ("Congradulations")} else {alert ("No that's incorrect, please try again...")}

}


</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: seems like this is not the complete code and on top of that your html tags are miss placed within the javascript.

Comment: Preferably, we don't do peoples homework here at SO. But BTW - What's the </FORM>-tag doing in front of the javascript function?

Comment: Nothing wrong with helping with part of homework, as long as it's appropriately tagged. Why do someone's work/job, but not homework? People are here to learn, let them, no matter the reason.

Answer (score 2):

You surely haven't given us the complete code we need to answer your question, but here's all the wrong things I can see in your code snippet fixed.

The most obvious wrong thing was the text `</FORM>` placed inside your `<script>` tag.

I also fixed your misspelling `Congradulations`, because I imagine that wouldn't go down too well :)

```
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getAnswer(input) {
    if (input == "3.14") { //What is the value of Pi to 2 decimal places?
        alert("Congratulations");
    } else {
        alert("No that's incorrect, please try again...");
    }
}
</script>
```

If this isn't helpful, please show us more of your file.

Comment: +1: lowercase HTML, valid syntax. You should add the starting <form> tag and an example input tag, and the code to trigger the getAnswer on submit to create a full standalone example - our question-poser has a lot to learn still ;)

Comment: A good suggestion, but I'd think it would be better to wait for the question-poser to come back and provide the complete code sample before doing anything else. She might have 20 different questions or something, who knows ;)

Comment: I'm addicted to JSFiddle I guess, but it's bedtime here. Leaving Olivia into your good hands!

Answer (score 0):

@Olivia try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title><br />

</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" onsubmit="getAnswer();"
  <p>
    <label for="textfield"></label>
  Q. What is the value of Pi to 2 decimal places?</p>
  <p>Answer 
    <input type="text" name="textfield1" id="textfield1" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getAnswer(input) {
    if (document.form1.textfield1.value == "3.14") { //What is the value of Pi to 2 decimal places?
        alert("Congratulations");
    } else {
        alert("No that's incorrect, please try again...");
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In form submit I give an action to call the function.

```
onsubmit="getAnswer();"
```

Inside the function I am getting the value as

```
document.form1.textfield1.value
```

Then simple steps.
Cheers

Comment: Doing someone's homework task for them rather than helping them do it themselves can only be counter-productive. The OP now has to work to learn anything from this, whereas posting your solution verbatim and going out to the pub is straightforward.